# Connected graph of $f$ and $g$ implies connected graph of $f\circ g$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Is it true that if two functions $f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ both have connected graph, then so does their composition $f\circ g$? I think, the answer is negative, and I would like to find an explicit example.

What we know:

- If $f$ or $g$ is continuous, then then graph of $f\circ g$ is connected.
- If the graph of a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is PATHconnected, then $f$ is continuous.
- Any Darboux function which is Baire 1 has a connected graph
- There is a counterexample to the above question in a (subtopology of) $\mathbb R^2$.

Any help is highly appreciated, thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is indeed negative, and a proof has been given already in the 70s, see Kellum: "Almost continuous functions on In". Fund. Math. 79 (1973), no. 3, 213--215.

A simpler proof can also be given using transfinite induction.